# i cannot Clone a Gitlab repository when i connected my github account to gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab, clone

Junior dev here!

I want to do a normal HTTPS clone to my PC. Using gitlab and git bash.. doing `git clone`+ https.. Next step is asking me my username and password from gitlab.. Its seems super easy but i created my Gitlab account throught my github account so now imposible to find my username and password.

I already tried `git config user.name`.
My github username + password 
Many other possible combinations of usernames and passwords 
like come on it should be so dificult !

- Do you have any hint to find my username + password??

 Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create an account by signing in with another service, the system creates a random password. This is true for almost any site, such as when you "sign in" somewhere with Google.

For [git authentication using HTTPS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#clone-with-https), there are two different things you can enter as a "password":

1. Your GitLab user account password. Since you don't know your password, then you should [reset your password](https://gitlab.com/users/password/new) first.
2. A [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token). This is required if you have multi-factor authentication (2FA) turned on in GitLab (which is possible to do even with signing in through GitHub).

Comment: Thank it make lot of sense i wrote the aanswer to solve my own problem lol. But you info really make seence i felt like an idiot infront of such a simple problem!!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! No problem, but marking my answer as the accepted answer, that gives me reputation points =D

Comment: Could you put a point in my question like that i reach 50point please.. i neeed to ask something in an aswer but stackoverflow doesn't allow me because i'm below 50 T.T

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arty-chan for your answer... It make lot of sense.

Today tired of trying possible passwords.. And not understanding why it wasn't working ... and even my boss got mad at me.. at the end i went to account settings:

- Disconect Github
- Change username and password

Now i have like a new account in gitlab (and my SSH keys work fine) i was really scared about changing the account name and having later problem with the SSH key.. but everything works now.